# Beginner question on Updating List Items using JSOM, REST and Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, sitepages

After doing a lot of research on REST, I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated. 
I want to users to be able to update the status of a Task by clicking a button which takes them to a url.

- The column is a choice column, and it's called **formStatus**, with (3) choices (**Ongoing**, **Completed**, and **Cancelled**)
- The url is to a Site Page called '**../../sitepages/taskslanding.aspx**', and the script lives on that site page in the content editor
- I've named the scrip '**jsomJs.js**', which is below:

`SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function()
        {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("=");
    var itemId = vars[1];
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var customList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tasks');
    var listItem = customList.getItemById(itemId);
    listItem.set_item('formStatus', 'Completed');
    listItem.update();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){ alert('Item updated'); }, 
        function(sender, args){ alert('Error: ' + args.get_message()); }
    );
    });`

I created a url for each list item, when clicked, fired the following (I'm using Task ID=5 just as an example)

```
<a href="../../sitepages/taskslanding.aspx?ID=5>Approve This Task</a>
```

**UPDATE 2/6/19**

For whatever reason, this code ONLY works on Task (ID #103). When entering the url `../../tasklanding.aspx?ID=103`, this code works as expected.

My Task IDs start at #33 and end on #945, wo #103 isn't even the earliest task! May I add that this code does *NOT* work on Task #100, #101, #102, #104, etc. Any one have ANY idea how to fix this? Or why it is happening?

Comment: Technically, this is not the REST API, this is JSOM (JavaScript Object Model), you might get better answers if you re-tag it as such.

Comment: The "Sorry, something went wrong" error page is not being caused by your Javascript throwing an error because it can't find the task with ID 870.  Whatever errors your Javascript throws will show up in the alert you put in your fail handler.  I would say the "Sorry something went wrong" error has more to do with the `taskslanding.aspx` page than your script.  Is that page checked out?  Is there some other web part on that page that's trying to do something?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The `../../SitePages/taskslanding.aspx` has (1) content editor on the page, which points to the Site Assets library js file containing the EXACT code in the original question. ID# 870 exists, and I am confused as to what isn't working. Do I need to reference the list name (Tasks) in the query string? Are we certain that I can run this script from a Site Page?

Comment: Hmm... I don't know if I would link to a `js` file from a CEWP.  You're doing that using the Content Link property?  If so, what I would do is this: create an HTML file that has `script` tags that link to your `js` file, and pull in the HTML file using the CEWP Content Link.  [See this other answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/254682/8992) where I am kind of explaining the same thing.  You definitely should be able to run that code on a site page, it seems like it's not getting loaded on to the page correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your script in my online environment, it works fine.

For error "No item exists...", confirm the ID exists.

The error "Input string was not in a correct format" caused by you got wrong ID parameter as there are other parameters, you could use below script to get parameter instead.

```
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
            var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
                var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
                if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];
            }
        }
```

Update:

Try combine as below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function()
        {
    var itemId =getQueryStringParameter('ID');
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var customList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tasks');
    var listItem = customList.getItemById(itemId);
    listItem.set_item('formStatus', 'Completed');
    listItem.update();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){ alert('Item updated'); }, 
        function(sender, args){ alert('Error: ' + args.get_message()); }
    );
    });
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
            var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
                var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
                if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Lee -- I updated my post so you can see the error messages and ensure the ID exists. Still getting an error and have no idea what it's about. As far as your suggestion, should I be adding this to my existing code or combining them?

Comment: Try the updated code.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I've updated and added the code (in both Script Ed. and Content Ed. -- screenshot here: [link](https://imgur.com/a/Rb511Ef)), it's still saying the item doesn't exist. I'm at a loss -- what am I not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

`SP.List.getItemById()` takes a number as an argument, but your query string parameter is a string. [(Documentation here.)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246019(v%3Doffice.15))

Try

```
var itemId = parseInt(getQueryStringParameter('ID'));
```

or

```
var itemId = Number(getQueryStringParameter('ID'));
```

Comment: Thanks, dude -- I tried them both, and still telling me the item doesn't exist. I've been at this for the past few days and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Yeah, sorry we have been unable to help figure it out.

Comment: Appreciate all of the time you've spent. Will update this if I ever figure it out.