# How to embed remote/dynamic JS in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, remote

I have several pages and instead of including my JavaScript in each page and then updating/amending the script in each page which is time-consuming, I just want each page to pull the script from a remote JS file so that I can only update that one file.

At the moment I have something like this embeded in each page (including H1 tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery132.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('#WebPartWPQ1').hide();
jQuery('#WebPartWPQ1_ChromeTitle').click(function()
{
jQuery(this).next('#WebPartWPQ1').slideToggle(500);
});
});
</script>
<h1>Heading Title</h1>
```

How do I get my custom scripts remote rather than embedded in each page?

Answer (score 3):

By exactly the same mechanism you are using to pull in the jQuery library.  If you take all that code you have in your script block there, and put it in a file called, for example, `myScript.js`, and you upload that script file to a document library somewhere (maybe the same place you have the jQuery file?), you can make the embedded HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery132.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/Style%20Library/Scripts/myScript.js"></script>
<h1>Heading Title</h1>
```

If you are not putting your script file in the same place as the jQuery file, then obviously make the `src` URL for the link to your script file point to the correct URL for your script file.

---

Addressing your comment - to add HTML in a similar way, you can create an HTML file with no `html`, `head` or `body` tags, just assume what's in that file will be inside the `body`, add that to a library somewhere in SharePoint, then put a [Content Editor Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/content-editor-web-part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc) on the pages where you want that HTML, and use the Content Link property of the CEWP to link back to your HTML file.

So for instance, you could put your two script links and your one `h1` and make a three line HTML file `myMarkup.html`.  Upload that to, for instance, a folder called "Html" in the Style Library of your site.  Then put a CEWP on the pages where you want to load those scripts and HTML, and in the Content Link property of the CEWP, put the URL to the HTML file:
`https://xxx.sharepoint.com/Style%20Library/Html/myMarkup.html`

[image: Content Link property]

That will inject your HTML as-is into the page.

Comment: Hi Dylan, I should've said that I actually tried this, but it wasn't working at first. Now I checked and made sure both .js files are published and it works :)

Comment: How can I add HTML code in the same way?

Comment: @Maciek updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: @Maciek you can also have `src` attribute use relative URLs. You can put `src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/myScript.js"` instead of `src="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/Style%20Library/Scripts/myScript.js"`... In order to include html into your page take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003363/10210195).

Comment: Thanks @DylanCristy for your help. I was wondering if there was another way instead of using <iframe> tag. By your description, it works pretty much the same as iframe ;), thanks

Comment: Actually, it is very much *not* like an iFrame.  With an iFrame, there is a completely separate `document` object in the iFrame, and a separate javascript context.  Javascript executing inside the iFrame cannot reach HTML elements outside the iFrame, and vice-versa, javascript executing on the main page cannot reach HTML elements inside the iFrame.  Using a CEWP, on the other hand, will inject your linked content directly into the page where the CEWP is.  That's why, if you are linking in some HTML, in your HTML you don't use `body` tags, you assume... (cont'd)

Comment: @DylanCristy I meant that the end result look similar, only when it comes to HTML. I have quickly noticed one problem with CEWP when embedding HTML. Specifically, when applying Accordion, when I click any option to expand, the whole page reloads: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol

Comment: ... that your content is going _inside_ existing `body` tags, because it is.  What happens is that during the ASP.NET page lifecycle, while the server is building the page, it sees that there is a CEWP on the page, gets the content (either from the CEWP directly or through the content link), and then injects that content directly into the `.aspx` page that it is loading.  Javascript pulled in to the page that way has access to any HTML elements anywhere else on that page, and there is no separate `document` or javascript context.  It's very different.

Comment: That reloading behavior comes from the fact that, if you are using a CEWP on a wiki page, the content is actually inside a `form` element.  You may have to capture your click events and `preventDefault` to keep the click from bubbling up to the `form` and causing the form to submit.

Comment: Thanks @DylanCristy for a detailed explanation. I will have a play with this :)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the version of SharePoint you are using.
But, in SharePoint 2010/13/16, you can create custom page layout and add references to your custom scripts in your page layout.

Then create your sharepoint pages using that page layout and you will have access to that custom script in all your pages.

**Sources**:

[Create A Custom Page Layout in SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-custom-page-layout-for-sharepoint-online/).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I'm using SharePoint Online.